# Return string: 'Days' or 'Months' or 'Years' based on N of days

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

I am using `moment.js` on `vue 3`.
I have a function that returns the difference of two `dates`. This is working but it is related to my question. The function is written like this:

```
methods: {
    getDateDifference (date) {
        var date = moment(date, 'YYYY MM DD')
        var today = moment()
        return today.diff(date, 'days')
    } 
}
```

Now, I can successfully get the difference of the `date` passed on to the function from the date `today`. The problem is I want to check if the `days` returned is greater than a week but less than a month, so that I can convert it to `weeks` rather than displaying `28 days` etc.. If also possible I want to include if `months` should be used instead of weeks when the `days` returned is greater than 28 days and render it also by `years` if the days returned is greater than or equal to a `year`

In short, instead of displaying

```
26 days
```

I need it to check if it can be converted into weeks so I can render it as:

```
3 weeks
```

Or if I can render it in `months` or `year`.

Comment: Put the difference in a variable. Then you can use `if` statements to return different results.

Comment: thanks @Barmar I just did that but I really feel bad on writing a very large chain of `if` `else`. Is there no other way?

Comment: I posted an answer, but it's just a chain of 4 `if/else`

Comment: @Barmar Well it is definitely smaller compared to what I've done. I'll give this a try. This looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moment` can deal this through the duration api:

Get the miliseconds:

```
methods: {
    getDateDifference (date) {
        var date = moment(date, 'YYYY MM DD')
        var today = moment()
        return today.diff(date)
    } 
}
```

Then use:

```
/* don't know the object holding methods */ 
let shortest = moment.duration(obj.methods.getDateDifference(date)).humanize();
```

Will get you months instead of days if it exceeds a month's time, years instead of months, etc.

[Moment.js duration.humanize](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/)

Comment: Didn't know about that API! Thanks @MinusFour, I'll check it. This is better imo to just utilize `momentjs`

Comment: For users like me that needs to configure the `humanize()` output, you can configure it by passing your configurations like this: `humanize(false, { d: 7, w: 4, m: 31, y: 365 })`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array that associates thresholds in days with the granularity of your result.

```
const periods = [
    {threshold: 366, period: "years"},
    {threshold: 31, period: "months"},
    {threshold: 7, period: "weeks"},
    {threshold: 0, period: "days"}
];

days = today.diff(date, "days");
for (let i = 0; i < periods.length; i++) {
    if (days >= periods[i].threshold) {
        return today.diff(date, periods[i].period);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! This seems to work. However there is a minor syntax error on `threshold: 31, period, "months"`. But since I'm using `momentjs` I think, I'll go to @minusFour's answer. +1, this is a great start for vanilla js users.